# How to change code of static library .a file Xcode Project for another Xcode project?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, github, cocoapods

Scenario like,

I have two xcode projects which has git repo.

Second Xcode project does not have target to run app in Device, But it has  libProject.a target and lots of lines of code.

First Xcode project has target to run app in Device and it uses above .a library by CocoaPod mechanism.

Now i want to update few things in Second Xcode project and wants to check in device, than pull update to First xcode project.
both projects belonds to git repo.

I had tried with to commit push of Second project and update pod of First project, But i could not get it.

**Edit***
First Xcode project has workspace too..

************ New Edit ************
something happening now. I have update code lines in static library which should be available to unit test only. I have did it. 
Now i have commit this code lines to new branch and make it default.
But when i going to update pod of static library from terminal i could not see changes in First Code workspace project.

[image]

please advise how to do this.

Comment: I don't see how you can do that using cocoapods.  I would use git submodule and an Xcode Workspace and avoid cocoapods completely, given you own both projects.

Comment: @trojanfoe  Yes, i am owner of both repo. But don't know exact flow. If you know please give me steps.

Comment: It's pretty involved but try a search for "xcode git submodule"

Comment: anyone with know this flow, please post answer.. I m in big trouble...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got it.

**Step 1.**

Update code in static library and do unit test. B'coz it is not like other project which has Device target.

**Step 2.**

Commit code and push to git. And make sure your commited code branch should be default one. If not merge to default or make it default branch.

**Step 3.**

Edit Pod file of First xcode project which is using Cocoapod mechnism.

Like

```
pod 'Name', :git => 'git@github.com:name.git’, :branch => ‘Default branch name'
```

*Add branch here only.*

**Step 4.**

Update this pod only. By terminal command.

```
pod update podname
```

**And got the update from static library.**

Comment: Is there a way to do something like for a third party library where I want to use a particular commit in my project without pods.

Comment: @Renascent i could not get you, Can you elaborate more?

Comment: What I am looking for is I have a project where I am not suppose to use pods but static library references of SDK and for ZbarSDK there is one particular branch which has WKWebView changes which is necessary so i can upload my app to AppStore. Issue is I have no idea how to get/create static library with that code. Do you have any reference or idea to do so ? anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can create workspace and add there First and Second project. And then in second project add linkage with library of 1st project. Any updates of library in First project will be automatically picked up by second project.

Comment: i could not get you.

Comment: If I proper uderstand what you need, please read next: http://sap-production.github.io/xcode-maven-plugin/site/userguide/Workspace.html